# casting address of swift struct to C pointer of specific type

Tags: swift

I am trying to understand what is the right way to cast the address of a struct in swift to a C pointer of a specific type. Here is what i am trying to do:

i have a C function that takes a pointer like such (C code):

```
myFunc(u8* data, u8 lengthOfData);
```

(NOTE: u8 is defined as unsigned char)

i would like to pass something to this function from swift, where is have:

```
let someData = SomeStruct(someValue: 1)
myFunc(&someData, sizeof(SomeStruct))
```

naturally, the swift compiler complains with:

```
'someData' is not convertible to '@lvalue inout $T3'
```

I assume this is because the it's missing the cast to u8*, as in C, i would call my fun like such:

```
myFunc((u8*)&someData, sizeof(SomeStruct));
```

I have tried the following things in swift:

```
UnsafePointer<u8>(&deviceInfo)
&deviceInfo as UnsafePointer<u8>
```

but both don't compile.

So What is the right way to cast the pointer type?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare the struct as a *variable*

```
var someData = SomeStruct(someValue: 1)
```

then you can use `withUnsafe(Mutable)Pointer()` to get a pointer:

```
withUnsafeMutablePointer(&someData) {
    myFunc(UnsafeMutablePointer($0), UInt8(sizeof(SomeStruct)))
}
```

This guarantees that the pointer is only used while the structure is
valid.

If the C function takes a *constant* pointer

```
 myFunc(const u8* data, u8 lengthOfData);
```

then you don't need mutable pointers:

```
withUnsafePointer(&someData) {
    myFunc(UnsafePointer($0), UInt8(sizeof(SomeStruct)))
}
```

But note that the layout of Swift structures is not defined and may
change. For data structures needed in both Swift and C it may be
safer to define them as C structures in the C header files instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried  this but get:  'someData' is not convertible to '@lvalue inout $T4'. As a sidenote, i should have mentioned, the struct IS defined in C.

Comment: @pixbroker: Have you defined the variable with `var` ? I had checked the code and it compiled for me.

Comment: Can you explain why someData has to be var?

Comment: Ok, if someData is var, i get this to compile. Thanks so much and apologies that i overlooked this detain in your answer. I too would like to understand why var is required in this case over let. Danke!

Comment: @DánielNagy: I can only guess. A constant might not have a memory location where the value is stored.

Comment: @Martin R: ok, thabks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to create a helper function to create a pointer:

```
func createPointerFrom<T>(elem: UnsafePointer<T>) -> UnsafePointer<T> {
    return elem
}

var someData = SomeStruct(someValue: 1)
let pointer = createPointerFrom(&someData)
```

Comment: Thank you. When i try this is get 'someData' is not convertible to '@lvalue inout $T6'.

Comment: Are you sure that someData is var instead of let?